# create new array from another array using "reduce" in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

I have an array/list like:

```
var mydata = [
  {"endTime": "123",
  "startTime": "2323",
  "lob" : ["a", "b", "c"]
  },
  {
  "endTime": "454",
  "startTime": "3232",
  "lob" : ["a", "b"]
  },
  {
  "endTime": "4545",
  "startTime": "2322",
  "lob" : ["c"]
  }
]
```

I want to map through this array and create another list in a way each "lob" and the [startTime, endTime] be added to a list, like below:

```
[
{"item": "a" , timeRange: [123, 2323] },
{"item": "b" , timeRange: [123, 2323] },
{"item": "c" , timeRange: [123, 2323] },
{"item": "a" , timeRange: [454, 3232] },
{"item": "b" , timeRange: [454, 3232] },
{"item": "c" , timeRange: [4545, 2322] },
]
```

How can I create my new list as above using reduce?

I have tried:

```
var mymap = mydata.reduce((x, y) => 
    y.lob.map((lob, index) => {
       x.push({"item": lob, "timeRange": [y.startTimestamp, y.endTimestamp]})
    })
  ), [])
```

I also tried using map. but if I have a big data, I assume reduce would have a better performance. I am looking for the best way to do this considering performance

Comment: Do you have to use `reduce` or can you use something else? e.g. `map`

Comment: I am interested to see how I can do it with reduce specifically

Comment: I am interested to see what have you tried to solve your own problem. Any JavaScript to share? Please read [ask], [edit] with a [mcve]

Comment: `arr =[];for(k of mydata){for(i of k.lob){arr.push({"item":i, "timeRange":[k.endTime, k.startTime]})}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this using reduce

```js
var mydata = [
  {"endTime": "123",
  "startTime": "2323",
  "lob" : ["a", "b", "c"]
  },
  {
  "endTime": "454",
  "startTime": "3232",
  "lob" : ["a", "b"]
  },
  {
  "endTime": "4545",
  "startTime": "2322",
  "lob" : ["c"]
  }
];

var newdata = mydata.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  curr.lob.forEach(el => {
    acc.push({ item: el, timeRange: [curr.endTime, curr.startTime] });
  });
  return acc;
}, []);
console.log(newdata);
```

Answer (score 2):

Rather than using [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), consider using [`flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) instead:

```js
const mydata = [
  { endTime: '123', startTime: '2323', lob: ['a', 'b', 'c'] },
  { endTime: '454', startTime: '3232', lob: ['a', 'b'] },
  { endTime: '4545', startTime: '2322', lob: ['c'] }
];

const result = mydata.flatMap(
  ({ lob, startTime, endTime }) => lob.map(
    item => ({ item, timeRange: [+startTime, +endTime] })
  )
);

console.log(result);
```